# How convert $GLOBALS to string?

Tags: php, mysql, global

I need save `$GLOBALS` into a field in MySQL, but...
`$GLOBALS` is an ARRAY

When I try with some function as

```
function array_to_string($array){
    $string = '';
    code...
    $string .= code...
    code...
    return $string;
    }

$string = array_to_string($GLOBALS);
```

this "`$string`" grow and grow... (is infinite)

Any idea please?

Comment: You can either use `json_encode()` or `serialize()`

Comment: Secondly, I suggest doing a bit more research before asking.

Comment: Can you post a sample array or part of your array ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try **implode(**) function....

The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.
For example..

```
<?php
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(" ",$arr);
?>
```

the output

```
Hello World! Beautiful Day!
```

Comment: But what about conversion of string back to array?

Comment: yeah, the OP seems to have lot of confusions xD

Comment: <?php
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>

Comment: for string to array conversion you can use.. explode() function

Comment: @Stackoverflow try my answer , it should work if there is any problem please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to JSON is adviced.

```
$string=json_encode($array);
```

> `json_encode` Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.

```
$array_back=json_decode($string);
```

> `json_decode` Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Comment: Sorry, my $GLOBALS include data UTF-8 just as: "pequeño, matías, etc..."

Then `code` $string = json_encode($GLOBALS, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`code` result in issue...

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Could you comment it here?

Comment: Or maybe you could try `json_encode(utf8_encode($string))`

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<sizeof($GLOBALS);$i++){$GLOBALS[$i]=utf8_encode($GLOBALS[$i]);}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `utf8_encode` and  `json_encode`

```
$arr = array_map('utf8_encode', $arr);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```